# why nginx can NOT remove the X-Powered-By header of PHP?

Tags: php, nginx

I use the `proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By` directive, but it doesn't work. I had to use the `expose_php` option in `php.ini`.

Is there anything different between the `proxy_hide_header` and the `expose_php` option?

Here is the configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .ailms.me;
    root /data/blog/ailms.me/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;        # i put it here, not working

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(\/.*)?$ {
        proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By ;   # still not working
```

Comment: I don't see why `proxy_hide_header` shouldn't work. Maybe there was a problem with your configuration?

Comment: ths! you are right . I use the wrong directive . I shoud use fastcgi_hide_header instead :)

Answer (score 4):

I sholud use **fastcgi_hide_header** instead ：)

because I use the nginx + fastcgi + php model , not nginx + php model